# nanoFramework webserver not recognizing routes with attributes

Tags: c#, nanoframework

I have set up an ESP32-WROVER as a web server using the nanoFramework.WebServer library.  It fires the route method when I use a route without attributes (//192.168.1.8/led) but not when I use a route with attributes (//192.168.1.8/led/on)

```
using (WebServer server = new WebServer(80, HttpProtocol.Http, new Type[] { typeof(ControllerGpio) }))
{
    // Start the server.
    server.Start();

    Thread.Sleep(Timeout.Infinite);
}
```

```
class ControllerGpio
{
    private static GpioController _gpioController = new GpioController();

    private static int ledPin = 2;

    [Route("led")]
    public void Led(WebServerEventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            var rawUrl = e.Context.Request.RawUrl.TrimStart('/');
            Debug.WriteLine($"Handling request {rawUrl}");
            var args = rawUrl.Split('/');
            if (args.Length < 2)
            {
                WebServer.OutputHttpCode(e.Context.Response, HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
                return;
            }

            // If the pin is not open
            if (!_gpioController.IsPinOpen(ledPin))
            {
                // Open pin
                _gpioController.OpenPin(ledPin);
                // Set pin mode to output
                _gpioController.SetPinMode(ledPin, PinMode.Output);
            }

            if (args[1].ToLower() == "on")
            {
                _gpioController.Write(ledPin, true);
            }
            else if (args[1].ToLower() == "off")
            {
                _gpioController.Write(ledPin, false);
            }
            else
            {
                WebServer.OutputHttpCode(e.Context.Response, HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
                return;
            }

            WebServer.OutputHttpCode(e.Context.Response, HttpStatusCode.OK);
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {
            WebServer.OutputHttpCode(e.Context.Response, HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
        }
    }
}
```

Case: //192.168.1.8/led
Debug output: Handling request led

Case: //192.168.1.8/led/on
Debug output:

Answer (score 0):

That looks like a bug. Please raise an issue in our GitHub [here](https://github.com/nanoframework/Home/issues).

Make sure to add the sample code above so it's easier to reproduce. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Probably need to decorate additional attributes

```
    [Route("led"), Route("led/on"), Route("led/off")]
    public void Led(WebServerEventArgs e)
```